# What is the best way in c# to determine whether the programmer is running the program via IDE or it's user?

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the best way in c# to determine whether the programmer is running the program via IDE or its user?

Answer (score 35):

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) {
    // You are debugging
}
```

Comment: So, what happens when user is running your program and then you attach debugger to it?

Comment: Then the user is running the app. with an IDE (assuming all debuggers are part of an IDE). I supposed the question poster would like to know if there's a debugger running, not necessarily if there's an IDE running.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to know if an application is running from e.g. Visual Studio, whether in debug-mode or not (you can run an app without debugger from VS as most people know), is mkus' solution.

Comment: tomekszpakowicz , you meant that the programmer has set to Debug instead of Release when building the program and then user runs that produced .exe file ?

Comment: I think he means that the program is started outside the IDE by launching the .exe from the bin/debug or bin/release folder.

Running an app. from the IDE doesn't mean that there's necessarily a debugger attached, nor that there isn't a debugger attached when you run outside an IDE.

Comment: @Webleeuw, I think that when we build an application with "debug" choise, it creates an .exe file in the 
bin\Debug folder. The created .exe file has some additional code related to debugging. Is it correct?

Comment: If a developer starts up a program under a debugger, (for instance, using GFLAGS to make an installed instance automatically start under a debugger for live production debugging,) the code is the runtime executable in its production environment, but this solution will make it think it is running under Visual Studio IDE. Checking for a debugger attached only tells you there is a debugger listening/watching/controlling, not that the code is running in an IDE, and that is what the question is asking. How to tell if the code is executing in production (normal install) or from the IDE.

Comment: @StarPilot: IMHO, it isn't clear which of several possible questions the OP had. If you are interested in production vs IDE, I've asked a question along those lines. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495095/app-data-path-during-development-versus-deployment/30513360  Unfortunately, the only answer I've gotten so far is a link to here, which isn't the same question. So I've concluded I have to try to determine it indirectly.

Answer (score 7):

```
public static bool IsInVisualStudio
{
    get
    {
        bool inIDE = false;
        string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
        {
            string prgName = args[0].ToUpper();
            inIDE = prgName.EndsWith("VSHOST.EXE");
        }
        return inIDE;
    }
}
```

Comment: if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(args) == false) { ... } is nicer imo :)

Comment: @Christian: `args` is a string array, not a string.

Comment: Besides, an equation to true or false is arguably too verbose in comparision with if(String.IsNullOrEmpty()) or if(!String.NullOrEmpty()). Just a little off the record for this question though.

Comment: Jon: Oops, you're right. My bad :/ I'll blame it on the early morning
Webleeuw: It's more verbose, but personally I find it easier to read compared to the negation operator :)

Comment: It's okay, but enabling the Visual Studio Hosting process is an option that can be turned off.

Comment: In more recent versions of Visual Studio (notably 2015), the execution string can end with any of these programs: QTAgent.exe, QTAgent32.exe, QTDCAgent32.exe, QTAgent_35.exe, QTAgent_40.exe, QTAgent64.exe, and many others. So you should check for `prgName.Contains("QTAGENT");`

Comment: Although the OP wanted WinForms I did a similar check in a web app for prgName.Contains("IISEXPRESS.EXE")