# WPF and Application.ThreadException

Tags: c#, wpf, error-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF global exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472498/wpf-global-exception-handler)

Hello SO, since "good old" WinForms days, I have been writing client code similar to

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
        CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += 
        Application_ThreadException;

    // actual application ;)
}

private static void Application_ThreadException (
    object sender, 
    ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // log error and terminate application ...
}

private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException (
    object sender, 
    UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // log error and terminate application ...
}
```

I have since graduated to WPF, and am curious about WPF mechanisms for error handling\reporting. Specifically,

- will an unhandled error on a WPF Gui thread still raise the `Application.ThreadException` event?
- is there a WPF analog to `Application.ThreadException`?
- is `AppDomain.UnhandledException` sufficient for **all** unhandled exceptions raised within a WPF application?

---

**EDIT:** sorry guys, just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472498/wpf-global-exception-handler), closing question. oh, to summarize

- WPF analog to `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException` is `System.Windows.Application.DispatcherUnhandledException` [it is an instance member, so reference `Application.Current` to find it!]

Now I can leave `System.Windows.Forms` for good! w00t!