# .NET Runtime Error causes process to crash! But there's no unhandled exception - Why? CLR bug?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .Net process which runs 24/7 which crashes once or twice per week. I have the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event hooked up to log4net and the event never gets fired! The process just crashes with logging anything! This looks like a .Net runtime/CLR bug as I just get a message in the Event Log saying ".NET Runtime 2.0 Error".

I am running .Net 3.0 Sp1.

Can some please help me figure out how to fix this?

**Event log message:**
.NET Runtime 2.0 Error Type: Error Event Id: 1000

Event log description: Faulting application appName.exe, version 0.0.0.0, stamp 4ca5d33d, faulting module mscorwks.dll, version 2.0.50727.3607, stamp 4add5446, debug? 0, fault address 0x0010724e.

Comment: Is that the extent of the message? Usually there is information like "Faulting application foo.exe...."

Comment: .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 are actually running .NET 2.0, just FYI

Comment: I doubt it's the CLR. Its more likely that some piece of code fails. Can you post the details from the event log?

Comment: Is there a description for this error in the EventLog?

Comment: Added extra info about faulting

Comment: what kind of application is it? WPF? WinForm? Windows Service? is there COM interop? Event viewer "Decription" contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that a StackOverflowException would not be caught like this, as there's nowhere for the code to run.  This would possibly be a good candidate for something that occurs on a reasonably regular basis - you may need to check through your code for infinite loops/recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe here is your [solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/2d10da32-3f57-4f9b-a509-e9864fc5bd16)

Answer (score 1):

So, some interesting feedback, but it may also be worth mentioning that different application types may throw exceptions on different event handlers.

For a Windows Service, we should be safe handling

```
static void Main (string[] args) 
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
        CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
}
```

For a WinForms application, we should also handle the additional unhandled event handler

```
static void Main (string[] args) 
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
        CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException +=
        Application_ThreadException; 
}
```

For a WPF application, a dispatcher event is provided for GUI exceptions

```
static void Main (string[] args) 
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
        CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException +=
        Application_DispatcherException; 
}
```

Also worth re-iterating, *any* unhandled exception typically results in program termination. Handling these events however gives us a chance to report and identify the root error.

Additional links that may help

[My question regarding unhandled GUI exceptions (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730349/wpf-and-application-threadexception)

[WPF global exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472498/wpf-global-exception-handler)

Answer (score 0):

Try to place a global try // catch on the entry point of your application.

Hope it helps.

Here it's talking about this error: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/2d10da32-3f57-4f9b-a509-e9864fc5bd16

Comment: good advice if the application is single threaded. unfortunately, unhandled exceptions thrown off-thread (by errant child threads in a multi-threaded application) will not be caught - typically resulting in program termination.

Answer (score 0):

look at under **error message 2**, also a hot fix included, this might or might not be your problem http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB913384