# Can you add a handler for WPF event exceptions?

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, ironpython

I have a single-threaded IronPython WPF application and if an event handler (`FrameworkElement.SizeChanged` for example) throws, the exception is just eaten and execution continues without any kind of notification.

Because of this I spent a lot of time today solving an "impossible" bug.

Does the same thing happen when using WPF from C#? What happens there if `SizeChanged` throws?

And is there a way to globally catch exceptions thrown by event handlers, but which don't terminate the application?

Answer (score 0):

A useful trick in c# for catching exceptions globally, is to wrap the entry point for your program in a try-catch block. Any unhandled exceptions will wind their way up to it. Depending on the nature of the exception, it may stop the program from terminating.

**EDIT**

Thought this might also be relevant to your interests.

[WPF global exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472498/wpf-global-exception-handler)