# Global Uncaught Exception Handler in Microsoft Surface?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception, pixelsense

Is there a possibility to register a global uncaught exception handler in a Microsoft Surface application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surface apps are just WPF apps... see [WPF global exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472498/wpf-global-exception-handler)

Comment: So i use this in OnApplicationActivated? Application.DispatcherUnhandledException

Comment: No, OnApplicationActivated can get called multiple times.  Open up you App.xaml.cs file and put it in "protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)"