# What's a good method of runtime error reporting for my WPF/C# 3.5 client app?

Tags: wpf, exception, client, reporting

I've thought of writing a service method that I'd call within the catch block of a try/catch that writes error details to a table for viewing.  Then I thought about if the services went down, the client app would have no way of reporting this data.  This lead me to the thought of popping up a text box containing the exception details and a Copy button.  The user would click the copy button to copy the text and paste it into an email to our support group.

It may sound crude, but I am new to client app development and haven't really given this much thought until now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Application.DispatcherUnhandledException Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472498/wpf-global-exception-handler) for  a summary (see Drew Noakes answer).

Be aware that there'll be still exceptions which preclude a successful resuming of your application, like after a stack overflow, exhausted memory or lost network connectivity while you're trying to save to the database.