# What's a good global exception handling strategy for Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm looking into doing some Unity3D scripting stuff, and I'd like to set up global exception handling system. This is not for running in the release version of the game, the intention is to catch exceptions in user scripts and also in editor scripts and make sure they are forwarded to a database for analysis (and also to send email to relevant devs so they can fix their shizzle).

In a vanilla C# app I'd have a try-catch around the Main method. In WPF I'd hook one or more of the [unhandled exception events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472498/wpf-global-exception-handler). In Unity...?

So far the best I've been able to come up with is something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public abstract class BehaviourBase : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        try
        {
            performUpdate();
            print("hello");
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            print(e.ToString());
        }

    }

    public abstract void performUpdate();

}
```

In other scripts, I derive BehaviourBase instead of MonoBehavior and implement performUpdate() instead of Update(). I haven't implemented a parallel version for Editor clases but I assume I'd have to do the same thing there.

I don't like this strategy, however, because I'll have to backport it to any scripts we grab from the community (and I'll have to enforce it on the team). The Editor scripts don't have a single point of entry comparable to MonoBehavior either, so I assume I'd have to implement exception safe versions of wizards, editors and so on.

I've seen suggestions about catching log messages (as opposed to exceptions) using  [Application.RegisterLogCallback](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application.RegisterLogCallback.html), but this makes me uncomfortable because I'd need to parse the debug log string rather than having access to the actual exceptions and stacktraces.

So... what's the right thing to do?

Answer (score 23):

Create an empty GameObject in your scene and attach this script to it:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class ExceptionManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        Application.logMessageReceived += HandleException;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    void HandleException(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type)
    {
        if (type == LogType.Exception)
        {
             //handle here
        }
    }
}
```

make sure there is **one instance**.

The rest is up to you. You can also store the logs in *file system*, *web server* or *cloud storage*.

---

Note that `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)` makes this GameObject persistent, by preventing it from being destroyed in case of scene change.

Comment: This has worked great for me so far, works during runtime

Answer (score 12):

There is a working implementation of RegisterLogCallback that I found here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/47659/callback-for-unhandled-exceptions.html

In my own implementation I use it to call my own MessageBox.Show instead of writing to a log file. I just call SetupExceptionHandling from each of my scenes.

```
    static bool isExceptionHandlingSetup;
    public static void SetupExceptionHandling()
    {
        if (!isExceptionHandlingSetup)
        {
            isExceptionHandlingSetup = true;
            Application.RegisterLogCallback(HandleException);
        }
    }

    static void HandleException(string condition, string stackTrace, LogType type)
    {
        if (type == LogType.Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(condition + "\n" + stackTrace);
        }
    }
```

I also now have the error handler email me via this routine, so I always know when my app crashes and get as much detail as possible.

```
        internal static void ReportCrash(string message, string stack)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Report Crash");
        var errorMessage = new StringBuilder();

        errorMessage.AppendLine("FreeCell Quest " + Application.platform);

        errorMessage.AppendLine();
        errorMessage.AppendLine(message);
        errorMessage.AppendLine(stack);

        //if (exception.InnerException != null) {
        //    errorMessage.Append("\n\n ***INNER EXCEPTION*** \n");
        //    errorMessage.Append(exception.InnerException.ToString());
        //}

        errorMessage.AppendFormat
        (
            "{0} {1} {2} {3}\n{4}, {5}, {6}, {7}x {8}\n{9}x{10} {11}dpi FullScreen {12}, {13}, {14} vmem: {15} Fill: {16} Max Texture: {17}\n\nScene {18}, Unity Version {19}, Ads Disabled {18}",
            SystemInfo.deviceModel,
            SystemInfo.deviceName,
            SystemInfo.deviceType,
            SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier,

            SystemInfo.operatingSystem,
            Localization.language,
            SystemInfo.systemMemorySize,
            SystemInfo.processorCount,
            SystemInfo.processorType,

            Screen.currentResolution.width,
            Screen.currentResolution.height,
            Screen.dpi,
            Screen.fullScreen,
            SystemInfo.graphicsDeviceName,
            SystemInfo.graphicsDeviceVendor,
            SystemInfo.graphicsMemorySize,
            SystemInfo.graphicsPixelFillrate,
            SystemInfo.maxTextureSize,

            Application.loadedLevelName,
            Application.unityVersion,
            GameSettings.AdsDisabled
        );

        //if (Main.Player != null) {
        //    errorMessage.Append("\n\n ***PLAYER*** \n");
        //    errorMessage.Append(XamlServices.Save(Main.Player));
        //}

        try {
            using (var client = new WebClient()) {
                var arguments = new NameValueCollection();
                //if (loginResult != null)
                //    arguments.Add("SessionId", loginResult.SessionId.ToString());
                arguments.Add("report", errorMessage.ToString());
                var result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(client.UploadValues(serviceAddress + "/ReportCrash", arguments));
                //Debug.Log(result);
            }
        } catch (WebException e) {
            Debug.Log("Report Crash: " + e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you tell me how do you call the reportcrash, do you parse for a specific string?

Answer (score 5):

Unity devs just do not provide us with tools like that. They catch exceptions internally in framework here and there and log them as strings, giving us Application.logMessageReceived[Threaded]. So, if you need exceptions to happen or be logged with your own processing (not unity's) I can think of:

1. do not use framework mechanics, but use your own so exception is not caught by framework
2. make your own class implementing `UnityEngine.ILogHandler`:

   ```
   public interface ILogHandler
   {
       void LogFormat(LogType logType, Object context, string format, params object[] args);
       void LogException(Exception exception, Object context);
   }
   ```

And use it as said in [official docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Logger-ctor.html) to log your exceptions. But that way you do not receive unhandled exceptions and exceptions logged from plugins (yes, someone do log exceptions in frameworks instead of throwing them)

3. Or you can make a suggestion/request to unity to make `Debug.unityLogger` (`Debug.logger` is deprecated in Unity 2017) have setter or other mechanism so we can pass our own.
4. Just set it with reflection. But it's temporary hack and will not work when unity change code.

   ```
   var field = typeof(UnityEngine.Debug)
       .GetField("s_Logger", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
   field.SetValue(null, your_debug_logger);
   ```

Note: To get correct stacktraces you need to set [StackTraceLogType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StackTraceLogType.html) in editor settings/code to ScriptOnly (most times it's what you need, I wrote an [article](http://deepscorn.blogspot.ru/2017/05/unitys-player-setting-logging.html) on how it work) And, when building for iOS, it is said that [Script call optimization must be set to slow and safe](https://support.apteligent.com/articles/knowledge_base/Unity-support-FAQ)

If interested, you can read how popular crash analytics tool works. If you look into crashlytics (crash report tool for android/ios), than you'll find out that it internally uses `Application.logMessageReceived` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` events to log managed C# exceptions.

If interested in examples on unity framework catching exceptions, you may look at [ExecuteEvents.Update](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/0155c39e05ca5d7dcc97d9974256ef83bc122586/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs?at=5.2&fileviewer=file-view-default#ExecuteEvents.cs-273) And another article from me with testing it catching exception in button click listener can be found [here](http://deepscorn.blogspot.ru/2017/05/why-unity-may-lose-frames-in-stacktrace.html).

Some summary on official ways to log unhandled exception:

I. Application.logMessageReceived is fired when exception happens on main thread. There are ways for it to happen:

1. exception caught in c# code and logged through `Debug.LogException`
2. exception caught in native code (probably c++ code when using il2cpp). In that case native code calls `Application.CallLogCallback` which results in firing `Application.logMessageReceived`

Note: StackTrace string will contain "rethrow" when original exception have inner exceptions

II. `Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded` is fired when exception happens on any thread, including main (it's said in [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceivedThreaded.html)) Note: it must be thread-safe

III. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` for example is fired when:

You call the following code in editor:

```
 new Thread(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        object o = null;
        o.ToString();
    }).Start();
```

But it causes crash on android 4.4.2 release build when using Unity 5.5.1f1

Note: I reproduced some bugs with unity missing stackframes when logging exceptions and assertions. I submited [one](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/assertion-logs-in-release-build-with-forceenableassertions-are-missing-some-stack-frames) of them.

Comment: "Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded is fired when exception happens on any thread". Does this mean Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded can also catch what AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException catches?

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned Application.RegisterLogCallback, have you tried implementing it?  Because the [logging callback](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application.LogCallback.html) passes back a stack trace, an error, and an error type (warning, error, etc).

The strategy you outline above would be tough to implement because MonoBehaviours don't just have a [single entry point](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html).  You'd have to handle OnTriggerEvent, OnCollisionEvent, OnGUI, and so on.  Each one wrapping its logic in an exception handler.

IMHO, exception handling is a bad idea here. If you don't immediately re-throw the exception, you'll end up propagating those errors in weird ways.  Maybe Foo relies on Bar, and Bar on Baz.  Say Baz throws an exception that is caught and logged.  Then Bar throws an exception because the value it needs from Baz is incorrect.  Finally Foo throws an exception because the value it was getting from Bar is invalid.

Comment: I get your point, however this is not intended for runtime - it's intended as a way of making sure that the tools harness for our team is thoroughly debugged -- which means I want to catch every exception and log it systematically; I might also want to take the opportunity to log context information that's not in the stack trace. I'm not interested in catching just so I can move on - I'm interested in catching so I can do remote forensics on errors coming from many users (often not in the same building).

Comment: @theodox No I get your point, I wasn't specifically referring to a release version.  But one way or another if you add the exception handling, it's there. So unless you're maintaining 2 separate code base or a really crufty BehaviourBase, I doubt there is going to be a quick and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin called [Reporter](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/36556) to receive an email of Debug Logs, Stack trace and screen capture on the moment of unhandled Error. Screen capture and stack trace are usually enough to figure out the reason of the Error. For stubborn sneaky Errors you should log more of suspicious data, build and wait again for the error.I Hope this helps.