# Unity - exception thrown in built, production app to not kill the application?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity player (in the editor) the exceptions thrown do not kill the application, worst case scenario they block some code that's after the exception.

Is it possible to have this feature in built production apps as well? So one can avoid "The app unfortunately stopped" crashes.

Comment: hint: use try...catch

Comment: and try catch everything from top to bottom? I did use that but obviously I can't think of everything.

Comment: Not to mention, in some cases Unity itself throws exceptions. I can't do anything against those :(

Comment: I do not think, you can do anything about unity exception - catching blindly everything and ignoring is also bad idea - however you can at least log those errors for further investigation

Comment: True that one. 
The problem is that I have features I used for like months, no issue, then tested on various (many weak) devices, no issue, then uploaded to Play, downloaded to my tablet that it was fine on before, and "Application stopped" :D I thought not-Play-downloaded builds shove exception under the carpet and that's why I didn't notice those (wouldn't explain why no error on my pc though).

Comment: I wonder if there is any "good practice" in this area?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061050/whats-a-good-global-exception-handling-strategy-for-unity3d

Comment: Not yet, but checking it now, thanks for linking.

Comment: What's with the solution that sends email to the dev? In that, and another one that uses `HandleException` the users say it catches runtime exceptions for them. Does that mean it's what I need? If so, those answers are superb.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is way to go

Comment: One more thing. That `HandleException`. Is that called automagically or do I have to use that inside a `catch` statement? The answer writer said "Attach this script to an empty game object in your scene. make sure there is one instance". That that and it handles all my exceptions thrown in the scene?

Comment: Kind of, you subscripbe with Application.RegisterLogCallback to intercept all log messages. So you need to set up exception handling (SetupExceptionHandling) as the first thing in your game

Comment: That will do. It will be the first thing in the `Awake` of my persistent gameobject.

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski Sorry to hold you up, just one more question. 
I did set up the stuff found on the answer, and made sure I throw a **lot of** exceptions inside my `Update`, and on every button click. 
I made a build, not development or debug (so a full production release) and on both my physical tablets the app did **not** get stopped, just e.g. some UI animations didn't play.
Does this mean I'm in the clear? Or does Google Play modify something with the app so that it gets more vulnerable?

Comment: I don't @agiro I am as much in the dark here as you are. I would imagine that reason for animation stopping is that something went wrong - it's just "hidden" by error catcher. I think this would require further testing.

Comment: I didn't just throw an exception, I on purpose f***** up the animation by looking for a `CanvasGroup` that's not there and trying to operate it. 
I didn't mention this but when I cleared my error everything went back to normal.