# VS2013 C# WPF W8 not launching

Tags: c#, wpf, launching

I have a weird problem.

I'm working on a Win8 set to a russian locale (though interface language is set to english). When I build my C# WPF application in VS2013 it then only works on other PCs if their locale is set to Russian too! I don't know why, but it is so.

The application itself uses only english characters in it's gui and code.

What can be the problem? I know it sounds ridiculus, but it is so! My friends all over the worlds tried to run it, about 10 of them, and it only worked if they set their locale to Russian!

If not it just does not start, without any errors

What am I missing?

Comment: I swear I saw this same question a few days ago, cant seem to find its duplicate however.  Did you create a new account?

Comment: Yes, and it was closed without a solution!

Comment: That is unfortunate.  This question seems better worded, but there is still very little to go on.  We need something that is reproducible in code, or an error message of some kind.

Comment: Nothing to reproduce - any program I make even just a blank one with 1 button on it - it is not launching if a system language\location is set to something different from Russian

Comment: Ah, ANY program you make.  So its something wrong with your environment then.

Comment: Do you have any luck compiling your code on a different machine?

Comment: Try setting your system to English then compile your program and try and run it.

Comment: Changed my system's location to US an still no luck. No, no luck compiling it on other machine. ANyway I'd like to know what is wrong with this one.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BvJDM4Qn

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YgdB7Fi8 and this - everything i could get from my friend

Comment: Can you give us more details on that XAMLParse error? Perhaps catch the exception via a special handler, then log it to disk. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472498/wpf-global-exception-handler/1472562#1472562 Make sure all your XAML tags are in English.