# New C# 6.0 String Interpolation statements don't compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

I am trying to implement some of the features in [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Connect-event-2014/116) but I'm not having much luck with the new **String Interpolation** syntax (I have everything else working, at least that's in this code).

I am using Visual Studio 2015 CTP6, I have configured it to use .NET 4.6 and have gone into the Build options to make sure I was specifying C# 6.0. I have also [followed the instructions here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-on-Visual-Studio-2015-CTP-6).

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using static System.Math;

namespace NewCsharp6Features
{
    public class C6Point
    {
        public int X { get; }
        public int Y { get; }
        public double Distance => Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y);

        public C6Point(int x, int y) { X = x; Y = y; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "(\{X}, \{Y})";
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting two of this compilation error:

> CS1009 | Unrecognized escape sequence

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, here?

Answer (score 9):

You need to proceed the string with a $

```
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"({X}, {Y})";
        }
```

Comment: You're correct, this is my problem. I wasn't aware that the syntax was changing.