# TextBox string with variables

Tags: c#, string, variables

I need to be able to make a textbox string take from variables and put the variables into a string.

```
textBoxEmailTemplateUT.Text = "The documents are as follows: FileNameHere ► {TotalPanelCountUtah} ► {TotalkWUtah} ► ElectricalUsageOffsetHere InformationAboutTheSystemHere If There are any questions or concerns, please reply to this email. Regards YourNameHere");
```

This is suppose to be a type of email template after someone does a few calculations in the other code (not displayed). The `{TotalPanelCountUtah}` and `{TotalkWUtah}` are both double variables that I need to be put into the string in the textbox. Some assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look as string formatting - here, for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx.  Your string has name placeholders and string.Format likes numbers.

Comment: Also consider writing a dedicated text builder method (using `StringBuilder`) if you want better control over formatting and plan to get a long message to send, especially if your code will be used by someone else. I find it terribly painfull to parse a lengthy line of code with endless variables and sometimes, with obscure meanings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using C# 6, you can use [string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194893/what-does-sign-do-in-c-sharp-6-0), as such:

```
string txt = $"The values are: {value1}, {value2}";
```

The syntax requires that you put a `$` before the string and enclose any variables within braces (`{}`).

Without string interpolation (pre-c#6), you can use:

```
string txt = String.Format("The values are: {0}, {1}", value1, value2);
```

This snippet of code does the same as the first one. [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx) will format a string, replacing each of the values between braces with its corresponding argument.

If:

```
double value1 = 0.5;
double value2 = 1.5;
```

then, for both of the snippets (interpolation and `string.Format`):

```
txt == "The values are: 0.5, 1.5"`
```

Comment: I appreciate everyone's responses. The $ approach worked best for what I'm trying to do with this code. I can understand String.Format would be incredibly useful as well as the .Replace method. I'll have to try playing with these more at a later time. For now, this gets the Calculator I'm building for my job working properly.

Again, thank you all of you who came out to help!

Answer (score 0):

as Clay mentioned in comment use `string.Format`

```
textBoxEmailTemplateUT.Text = string.Format("The documents are as follows: FileNameHere ► {0} ► {1} ► ElectricalUsageOffsetHere InformationAboutTheSystemHere If There are any questions or concerns, please reply to this email. Regards YourNameHere",TotalPanelCountUtah, TotalkWUtah);
```

where TotalPanelCountUtah TotalPanelCountUtah are double type

Answer (score 0):

`string.Format` is generally preferred, but I included a second approach using `string.replace` below. It is probably also a good idea to round the values before displaying them.

```cs
double val1 = 1.2345;
double val2 = 8.7654;

// recommended
textBox1.Text = string.Format(
    "Value one is {0:0.00}, and value two is {1:0.00}.",
    val1, val2);

// also an option
textBox1.Text = "Value one is val1, and value two is val2."
    .Replace("val1", Math.Round(val1, 2).ToString())
    .Replace("val2", Math.Round(val2, 2).ToString());
```