# System.Threading.ThreadAbortException in classlibrary

Tags: wpf, multithreading, exception

I have a wpf application which will call a class library as a plugin to connect with wcf service every time. When call a service method in class library, it will give the above exception. And the exception message is 
`er = {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}`Even the stack trace also has the above message. What is the solution?

Comment: Find out who is aborting threads and make them stop. Aborting threads is almost never a good idea.

Comment: I don't abort any threads in program. Its automatically get aborted.

Comment: Yeah, find out what component did this and why. Set the debugger to break on all exceptions and see where that exception is coming from.

Comment: Voting to close because there is no information here to find the reason for this error. Add any required information and reopen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472498/wpf-global-exception-handler

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing here, as you don't provide much code. But in your main application make sure to add the following eventhandlers;

```
DispatcherUnhandledException
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException
```

As also documented in this thread:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472498/wpf-global-exception-handler
```

Log your exceptions with something like Log4net. Regarding WCF, **all calls** should be wrapped in a try catch block.

If your error is WCF related you can take your service's app.config file and add the following configuration:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel"
          switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true" >
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="myUserTraceSource"
          switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="xml"
       type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
       initializeData="c:\temp\wcf.svclog" />
  </sharedListeners>
```

This will log all WCF activity to c:\temp\wcf.svclog which you may view using the tool SvcTraceViewer.exe located in your win sdk directory.

Hope it helps

Stian