# WPF DataGridView CTRL+C Try Catch

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagridview, clipboard

i'm having issues with CTRL + C on my app.

I know for a fact that when a certain program (DameWare for example) is locking the clipboard my app getting exception when using it (OpenClipboard Failed CLIPBRD_E_CANT_OPEN HRESULT:0x800401D0).

So whenever i use the clipboard i wrap it with a try catch and handle it.

what i can't figure out, is how to handle a "ctrl + c" event from the dataGrid (i must mention that "ctrl + c" within a textbox works fine for some odd reason i don't understand).

Is there any way i can try catch or handle a CTRL + C within  a DataGrid?

i think my code is irrelevant for this issue hence i'm not posting it.

thanks in advance.

** EDIT **

I never found a solution to this one but i did manage to work around it.
what i did was creating an `Application_DispatcherUnhandledException` method to handle `Unhandled exceptions` that are coming from the UI. 
And i check the exception message that i get from the `DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs`

there are loads of info on the net about it:

[WPF global exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472498/wpf-global-exception-handler)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90866/Unhandled-Exception-Handler-For-WPF-Applications.aspx

Hope it hellps.