# Application wide exception handling

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I have a requirement where I need to implement an exception handler where any unhandled exception thrown by the application will need to be presented to the user (i.e a popup), and the user can then choose to submit the error to support, or ignore the error.

There are a few questions about the best practices of something like this. The first thing that comes to mind is catching unhandled exceptions for the entire application appears to be a pretty bad idea. But I'm uncertain on what approach I can take to fulfill this requirement.

Here's an idea I have thought about already:

I can subscribe to the `DispatcherUnhandledException` event in the `App` class, although I'm uncertain whether this will catch *all* unhandled exceptions. I can then use this to show a popup window for example. Essentially, this will be like wrapping the whole application in a `try ... catch`.

Are there any particular patterns I can follow to achieve this kind of functionality? Also, is wrapping the entire application in a try/catch even a good idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would it be not a good idea? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472498/wpf-global-exception-handler

Comment: What you probably want to handle is `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`

Comment: Why is catching all unhandled exceptions a bad idea? Seems to be exactly what you need, or are there some unhandled exceptions you want to leave for Windows to close you application?

Comment: The link by @L-Three describes all the ways you can catch unhandled exceptions. You can't wrap the entire application in a try/catch block as everything except the initialization of the first form occurs in response to events