# How to handle an exception globally while make sure the app won't exit?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework

Here is an EntityException which occurs when the EntityFramework can not contact the Sql database, but just the database is closed, the rest of the app can still work fine. So, is there a way? I tried to use 
  `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`
but the app still exit in release mode.   Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF global exception handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472498/wpf-global-exception-handler)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you're looking for this:

```
 public partial class App
{
    public App()
    {
        this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += OnDispatcherUnhandledException;
    }

    private async void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        await ErrorService.HandleError(e.Exception, "An unhandled exception occurred", true, true);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```