# How to Catch Exceptions in WPF when Calling a WCF Service

Tags: wpf, wcf, exception

How can I catch exceptions in WPF when calling a WCF Service?

Answer (score 3):

Basically you'll have three approaches:

- Rethrow `FaultException` on your regular try/catch
- Mark your `OperationContract` with `FaultContract` attribute and translate your Exception to your custom Fault object, manually
- To implement a `IErrorHandler` behavior and let it handle WCF exceptions to you

This link can explain these options: [Simplifying WCF: Using Exceptions as Faults](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/07/simplifying-wcf-using-exceptions-as-faults/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this has already been covered by this question on stack overflow. [WPF Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793100/globally-catch-exceptions-in-a-wpf-application)

Bob.