# WPF application crashes when opened the application using remote desktop connection

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

All,

I am running my WPF application using VS2010 and it is running fine in my machine. But when I remote desktop into my machine(same machine) from a different machine, application crashes suddenly when I drag a scrollbar. The same functionality works fine in my machine.

Is there anything to do with the RDP session? Ideally speaking I am running the application from my machine with and without RDP.

could anyone help me out in this issue, I have been looking into this from several days

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any event log entries from the crash?

Comment: A reach but update the graphics drivers on both machines.   For that matter all service packs and updates.

Comment: Have you subscribed to the Unhandled exception event? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793100/globally-catch-exceptions-in-a-wpf-application

Comment: Do you do some kind of ui-thread marshalling?

Comment: I am using TPL for parallel threading. I can see ERROR in application event log with Micorosoft Visual Studio as Source.

Comment: This bug report may be relevant:  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1930838/animated-wpf-effects-cause-hard-crash-over-rdp-under-certain-conditions

Answer (score 0):

As grantnz suggested, you can try subscribing to the unhandled exception event.  That will allow you to catch the exception and view the stack trace for more details.  If using .net framework 2.0 or above, thread exceptions do not get caught.  To get around this, you can add legacy exception handling to your app.config:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Note:I recommend only using the above for debugging and not distributed for production.

Comment: I have tried adding exception handling code but of no use. It still fails without giving any ERROR.

Comment: I have also same issue, is there any solution...?