# How to look up which exception was thrown when running a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

When I start a WPF application and an exception is thrown by some method the program crashes. For debugging reasons it would be very interesting to see the exception stack. But where will it be printed?

Comment: Try this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793100/globally-catch-exceptions-in-a-wpf-application

Comment: And application log too: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2013/07/31/10438571.aspx

Comment: @Tony thank you! Hmm... I was hoping for a simple answer. It is frustating to see there is no easy way. :-(

Comment: You could add a uncaught exception handler.  If you want me to post code let me know.

Comment: @Blam Sure, would be great to see.

Comment: Added a code sample that has an appdomain handler, too. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should hook up to the [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event and the [Application.DispatcherUnhandledApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx) event inside the App constructor or in the App.OnStartup .

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    //Either here
    public App()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
        Dispatcher.UnhandledException += Dispatcher_UnhandledException;
    }

    //Or here
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
        Dispatcher.UnhandledException += Dispatcher_UnhandledException;
    }

    void Dispatcher_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        //add logging
    }

    void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        //add logging
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In app.xaml.cs just add an uncaught exception handler
Be aware that exceptions from unmanaged code and elude this handler

```
this.DispatcherUnhandledException += new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(App_DispatcherUnhandledException);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Exception.StackTrace))
{
   sb.AppendLine("e.Exception.StackTrace ");
   int count = 0;
   foreach (string line in e.Exception.StackTrace.Split('\n'))
   {
       sb.AppendLine(line.Trim());
       count++;
       if (count > 10) break;
   }
}
```