# WPF Application closes while trying to find static resource

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some `Image` components on the page and some static images defined in App.xamp. On startup I need to fill `Image` components with random static images.

```
int[] squareImageSources = new int[13]; 
Random rnd = new Random();
Image[] squareImages = new Image[13];

public Page1()
{
    squareImages[0] = i0;
    squareImages[1] = i1;
    squareImages[2] = i2;
    squareImages[3] = i3;
    squareImages[4] = i4;
    squareImages[5] = i5;
    squareImages[6] = i6;
    squareImages[7] = i7;
    squareImages[8] = i8;
    squareImages[9] = i9;
    squareImages[10] = i10;
    squareImages[11] = i11;
    squareImages[12] = i12;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int randomNumber = rnd.Next(28);
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        while (squareImageSources.Contains(randomNumber))
            randomNumber = rnd.Next(28);
        squareImageSources[i] = randomNumber;
        squareImages[i].Source = (BitmapImage)System.Windows.Application.Current.FindResource("s" + Convert.ToString(randomNumber + 1)); //application closes here
    }
}
```

**App.xaml:**

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="s1" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Photos/1.png"/>
<BitmapImage x:Key="s2" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Photos/2.png"/>
.....................................................
<BitmapImage x:Key="s28" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Photos/28.jpg"/>
```

But application just closes, I recieve no exception. What can be wrong with this code?

**UPD:**

Tried this way:

```
try
{
    BitmapImage bi = (BitmapImage)System.Windows.Application.Current.TryFindResource("s" + Convert.ToString(randomNumber + 1));
    squareImages[i].Source = bi; //nullReferenceException
}
catch
{

}
```

`catch` catches NullReferenceException. How is that possible? I can use this recource in designer and if works fine.

Comment: Have you enabled Common Language Runtime Exceptions in Debug->Exceptions? Also, consider  to enable WPF Tracing via your config-file (rightclick and select to configure might start a wizard - it does for WCF)). It gives details that I don't know how to get otherwise.

Comment: you are doing quite a bit in that line. Did you try to seperate that line, to verify that the FindResource call is the problem? After you did that you can try to catch the Exception (like here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.findresource(v=vs.110).aspx) and then post the result here.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: [FindResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.findresource(v=vs.110).aspx) may throw `ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException`. You are not handling it. If you don't handle [unhandled exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/793100/1997232) as well then application will simply crash. As for `TryFindResource` it may return `null`. You are getting `NullReferenceException` because `squareImages[i]` is not `Image` (but `null`).

Comment: `FindResource()` and `Resorces[]` are giving completely same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign something to

```
squareImages[i].Source = ...
```

you do not show where `squareImages` is defined. And it seems like the value of `squareImages[i]` is `null`.

This will throw `NullReferenceException` in both cases (in first one will crash application).

Comment: No, that's definitely not the problem. `squareImages` is initialized. Added initialization to the question.

Comment: It **is** the problem. Just set a breakpoint. `Page1` and then suddenly `UserControl_Loaded` is suspicious.

Comment: Thank you! I've placed `squareImages[0] = i0;...` before `InitializeComponent();`, not after. I forgot that `InitializeComponent();` initializes i0.