# Crashes loading surface when deployed on non-development machine

Tags: scichart

I've just coped a release version of my application onto a fresh non-development machine and I've found whenever a Scichart surface loads the program crashes with the standard "Application has stopped working: A problem caused the program to stop working correctly."

I've got two identical machines that I've loaded the application onto, however, I was using one while using the trial version of Scichart, so I'd installed the trial onto it so I was able to run the software for a demo. Now I've got a full license, it's all fine on that machine. But I can confidently rule out hardware.

I think I might not be deploying the license correctly? But if that were the case the charts should be blank rather than crash the program.

I've updated to the latest 4.05 release.

Any ideas where to look for the problem? Cheers.

Comment: Do you have the Exception message / can you provide inner exception? Licensing how-to for SciChart can be found at www.scichart.com/licensing-scichart

Comment: It's only happened with release on a machine without VS, so no exception message is reported. I have tried to put a catch-all, but may have commented it out! I'll double check

Comment: Hi Joe, if you're not even hitting the catch all, it may be .NET Runtime missing. The app won't start at all unless you have that dependency. I've also added some more ideas for you in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like either the application itself is throwing an Exception, or the .NET4.0 Runtime is not installed on the target PC.

To check the latter, ensure that [.NET4.0 Runtime](http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html) (or 4.5/4.6 if you are compiling for this version) is installed on the target PC.

If that doesn't help, you need to write a [global catch-all handler in your WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793100/globally-catch-exceptions-in-a-wpf-application) and log the exception that you are getting. Then, from the exception message, stack trace, inner exception (if any) you should be able to identify the problem.

Also, the WPF Charts with DirectX Hardware Acceleration have some dependencies, but SciChart is designed to [fall back to software rendering](http://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/17264/44/easy-fallback-from-directx-to-software-rendering-without-code-behind) if dependencies are not found.

Finally, certain components in SciChart, such as [WPF 3D Charts](http://www.scichart.com/wpf-3d-chart-features), require the [Visual C++ 2013 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=40784). There should be an exception thrown if VC++2013 is not found on the target PC. But apart from that, the dependencies are pretty slim.

Comment here with what you find.

Comment: Getting: "The SciChart Direct3d10RenderSurface is not supported on this PC, reasons: HasDirectXRUntimeInstaller: False". I wonder if this is because I'm explicitly setting s:SciChartSurface.RenderSurface to s3D:Direct3D10RenderSurface on each graph.

Comment: I notice here you set up a fallback, http://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/17261/0/high-quality-vs-high-speed-vs-directx-renderer-plugins. Can I do this for the whole application, rather than in every graph?

Comment: Yes of course, the above uses an Attached Property. You can apply an Attached Property to every SciChartSurface by using an implicit style: https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/implicit-style/

Comment: Please also see http://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/17262/44/creating-and-deploying-applications-with-the-direct3d10rendersurface which talks about how to redistribute the DirectX Runtime with your application. In the future we are planning to remove this dependency but for now you need to deploy it with your app.