# WPF catch all exceptions

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to catch all exceptions in my WPF App. I tried the following code but it is not working I don't know why?

```
<Application x:Class="DBFilter.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
         Exit="Application_Exit"               
         DispatcherUnhandledException ="AppDispatcherUnhandledException"
         >
<Application.Resources>
     
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new 
UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(AppDomainUnhandledExceptionHandler);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += new 
ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
        Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += new 
DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(AppDispatcherUnhandledException);
}

void AppDomainUnhandledExceptionHandler(object sender, 
UnhandledExceptionEventArgs ex)
    {
        Exception ex = (Exception)ea.ExceptionObject;    
 MessageBox.Show(ex.Exception.InnerException.Message);
    
    }

void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.InnerException.Message);
    }                       

void AppDispatcherUnhandledException(object 
sender,DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.InnerException.Message);
    }
```

Later, I will write all exceptions to a log table.

Comment: Not every exception has an inner exception.

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens when you run your program? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Globally catch exceptions in a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793100/globally-catch-exceptions-in-a-wpf-application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Udontknow noted in his comment, not every exception has inner exception(s). Also, there can be, for instance, *two* inner exceptions. Thus, to correctly collect *all* exceptions, you can use the following helper `GetAllExceptions` extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetAllExceptions(this Exception ex)
    {
        int x = 0;
        string pattern = "EXCEPTION #{0}:\r\n{1}";
        string message = String.Format(pattern, ++x, ex.Message);
        Exception inner = ex.InnerException;
        while (inner != null)
        {
            message += "\r\n============\r\n" + String.Format(pattern, ++x, inner.Message);
            inner = inner.InnerException;
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
try
{
    throw new Exception("Root Error", innerException: new Exception("Just inner exception"));
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    WriteLine(ex.GetAllExceptions());
}
```

**Output:**

```
EXCEPTION #1:
Root Error
============
EXCEPTION #2:
Just inner exception
```