# catch resize window exeption event wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

In my wpf application when I resize the window I'm getting an exception only on windows server, but on win 10 there is no exception.

My question:

How do I catch this exception of resizing?

my goal is something like:

**XAML:**

```
.
.
SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged" WindowStyle="None">
```

**Code behind:**

```
void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e){
 MessageBox.Show(theExeptionString);
}
```

I'm not using debugger because I want to test it on a computer without visual studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Globally catch exceptions in a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793100/globally-catch-exceptions-in-a-wpf-application)