# VB.net Application does not start on other machine

Tags: vb.net, frameworks, invalidoperationexception, powerpacks

i have following problem:
i made an app in Visual Studios in Basic. Now i want to run the app on an other machine but it does not start and shows following error:

Problemsignatur:

Problemereignisname: CLR20r3

Problemsignatur 01: Testprogramm.exe

Problemsignatur 02: 1.0.0.0

Problemsignatur 03: f355e3ea

Problemsignatur 04: Microsoft.VisualBasic

Problemsignatur 05: 14.6.1055.0

Problemsignatur 06: 563c1cc7

Problemsignatur 07: 155

Problemsignatur 08: 86

Problemsignatur 09: System.InvalidOperationException

Betriebsystemversion: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48

Gebietsschema-ID: 1031

Zusatzinformation 1: 898a

Zusatzinformation 2: 898a9829d4d4c6c6490f3f985d792a98

Zusatzinformation 3: 3c23

Zusatzinformation 4: 3c23ce3d18c8aa0d975d086a3c11fef

on the other machine is .net Framework 4.6.1 and Powerpacks installed. Visual Studio is not installed.

I´m able to install the app but when i try to start it i get the error. I also get the same error if i start the exe.

On the pc where i made the app both, just starting the exe or install it and start it then, works fine.

Thanks for your help! 
JB

Comment: What is the related message? Have you hardcoded some file paths (or forgot to carry over some required files)? Where is the program installed? Do you have access rights to that path? (...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Comment: make sure that you have set the configuration manager settings to "Any CPU" or x86. if it's for a legacy system then make sure you are using an older version of visual studio and check any errors (for example, syntax errors/missing keywords).

Answer (score 0):

It throws a `System.InvalidOperationException`. Catch the error (with `try catch` or a global exception handler) and show us more (eg. the `Exception.Message`).

See [Globally catch exceptions in a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793100/globally-catch-exceptions-in-a-wpf-application) for WPF.

Comment: how can i do this? the app does not even start

Comment: @JB_ - The app _is_ starting, otherwise there could not be a `System.InvalidOperationException`.  You should be able to catch that with a global exception handler.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider making an [edit] to your answer to give more details about your proposed exception handler.