# Unable to run WPF desktop app on some PC's

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017, setup-deployment, .net-framework-version

I have created a WPF desktop application using the community edition of Visual Studio 2017.

The problem that I am facing is that my application does not run on some PCs where I try to install my application whereas it runs fine on others. On the OCs where it does not work, when I execute my application no errors are thrown but in the task manager the status of my process changes to **suspended** and then the process is removed from the set of running processes.

I am able to debug and run application on my PC (Win 10 64 bit OS), and on couple of other PCs that have Windows 8 64 bit OS, but the ones on which the application fails to run are Windows 10 PCs, but I am not sure if Win 10 is the problem since the application is running on my PC.

When creating the installer for my application, I have the following options selected:

> .Net framework 4.6.1(x86 and x64) as a pre-requisite.
>
> Download prerequisites from the same location as my application.

I need help in debugging what is cause for this problem, since at this point I do not know what is stopping my application from running. How can I debug what is going wrong on these deployment PCs?

I have tried installing on different PCs, but could not identify the reason why it is working on some whereas not on others.

I thought maybe the "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2017" is a requirement so I downloaded and installed on the client machine but this too did not help.

I also disabled the anti-virus software, but this too did not help.

Comment: What kind of setup are you using?

Comment: Did you try globally catching unhandled exceptions?  If not, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/793100/2348184

Comment: Did your program consume a lot of memory?

Comment: Read Windows application event log first to see if it crashed for certain reasons. Edit the question to include the full message if found.