# Why App.DispatcherUnhandledException handler doesn't catch exceptions thrown by App constructor?

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

Please look at the following code:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
        public App():base()
        {
                this.DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException;
                throw new InvalidOperationException("exception");
        }

        private void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message);
                e.Handled = true;
        }
}
```

Why the handler doesn't catch the exception thrown by App constructor?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46804709/591656

Answer (score 1):

> Why the handler doesn't catch the exception thrown by `App` constructor?

Simply because there is no dispatcher running before the `App` has been constructed.

This is the `Main` method that is generated for you by the compiler:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    App application = new App(); //<-- your throw here
    application.InitializeComponent();
    application.Run(); //<-- and there is no dispatcher until here
}
```

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.run?view=netframework-4.8):

> When `Run` is called, `Application` attaches a new `Dispatcher` instance to the UI thread. Next, the `Dispatcher` object's `Run` method is called, which starts a message pump to process windows messages.

You cannot call `Run` before the you have actually created the `App` object.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked this way to do the same.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
        public App():base()
        {
                Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += new
                   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(
                      AppDispatcherUnhandledException);
                throw new InvalidOperationException("exception");
        }

void AppDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender,
           System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            //do whatever you need to do with the exception
            //e.Exception
              MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message);
                e.Handled = true;

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instance of App failed to construct, therefore Application.Current doesn't make any sense. You should subscribe on AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException

```
public App() : base()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
    throw new InvalidOperationException("exception");
}

private void CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
}
```