# Send information to main class

Tags: c#, parent

My program has network functionality so to avoid messagebox spam in case of network problem i display errors from a collection.

```
internal class VM_Main
    {   ...
        public ObservableCollection<string> Errors { get; } = new observableCollection<string>();
        ...
    }
```

This collection is displayed in my XAML window.

```
public MainWindow()
    {    ...
        vm_Main = new VM_Main();
        dgdErrors.ItemsSource = vm_Main.Errors;
        ...
    }
```

This is OK.

My problem is when i use objects from other classes in variables. How can I send information to the errors collection to report an error?

```
internal class VM_Main
{   ...
    public ObservableCollection<string> Errors { get; } = new observableCollection<string>();
    ...
    List <Customers> allCustomers = new List<Customer>()
}

public class Customer
{   ...
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public Customer()
    {
        try{ // Network work }
        catch (Exception ex) {   ????? Errors.Add(ex.Message) ????  }
    }
    ...
}
```

"Errors doesn't exist in the current context."
Of course, but how am I supposed to do ?

Comment: Try this => [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793100/globally-catch-exceptions-in-a-wpf-application) for set globally catch

Comment: I don't know what framework you are using, nor the version or options, but normally you would use Dependency Injection and add an `ILogger` to every place you need it. Then you can log with `Severity.Error`. Read [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/). Of course you can make your own `ErrorService`, if you really want full control, but think about how the experienced people at Microsoft have solved such things for you.

Comment: @JHBonarius I'm using c# with .NET Framework 4.7.2. There is something pre-built for this kind of situation ?

Comment: You could use a logger package like Serilog or log4net. [look here for an example](https://github.com/rishabhverma17/WPF-Logger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fully OOP implementation design using singleton pattern (lazy approach). Further info [Singleton pattern](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton)

1- Define the singleton class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ErrorToConsole
{
    public sealed class Singleton
    {
        private ObservableCollection<String> Errors = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy = new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

        public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

        private Singleton()
        {

        }

        public string AddError(string strError)
        {
            Errors.Add(strError);
            return strError;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> GetErrors()
        {
            return Errors;
        }

    }

}
```

2- Calling the singleton class to add and retrieve errors.

```
using System;

namespace ErrorToConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var singleton = Singleton.Instance;

            try
            {
                
                //Adding some errors here
                singleton.AddError("aaa");
                singleton.AddError("bbb");
                singleton.AddError("ccc");
                singleton.AddError("ddd");

                throw new Exception("Throwing exception");
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Adding exception message here
                singleton.AddError(ex.Message);

                //this is just to show that all the errors where added to the singleton collection.
                foreach (var val in singleton.GetErrors())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(val);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding global state this way is not a good design.

Comment: im trying to keep it simple. i would make a singleton actually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Why is that a bad design ? Will it be an issue in my situation ? There is a "good practise" for management error display ?

Comment: not at all indeed singleton pattern is global @JHBonarius

Comment: @Eldora248 i can provide you an example using singleton pattern. please let me know.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator yes, I'm very insterested by that !

Comment: Updating my answer shortly :)

Comment: done feel free to ask any question

Comment: Thanks you ! But I am not using a console application but a WPF with MVVM. My datagrid where the errors are displayed is binded to the vm_Main's ObservableCollection Errors.

Comment: The pattern is agnostic to the technology stack. the console application is for you to test the pattern. You just need the Singleton class

Comment: Okay, I will try it !

Answer (score 1):

You make an interface:

```cs
public interface IErrorReport
{
    void AddError(string message);
}
```

You then let your main window implement that interface:

```cs
internal class VM_Main : IErrorReport
{
    ...
    public void AddError(string)
    {
        Errors.Add(string);
    }
}
```

In your Customer constructor you add a parameter:

```cs
public Customer(IErrorReport report)
{
    try
    { 
        // Network work 
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {   
        Report.AddError(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Then all you need is to pass a reference to the main window when you create the customer:

```cs
internal class VM_Main
{   ...
    public ObservableCollection<string> Errors { get; } = new observableCollection<string>();
    ...
    List <Customers> allCustomers = new List<Customer>(this);
}
```

Comment: this approach works as well, but imho does not make sense to add the interface implementation everywhere and make a constructor with one parameter related to errors.

Comment: You only make the implementation once. Only the mainview needs to know how to add an error, other classes just need to know an interface that can do it for them.

Comment: Have a look at IProgress which is sort of the same methodology: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=net-6.0.

Comment: The interface also makes it easier to write unit tests, because you can mock it or write a simple implementation of it. A singleton will make it harder to unit test.

Comment: Thanks ! But what if Customers have an other collection and I need to send error from this deeper object ?

Comment: Just store the IErrorReport reference in Customer and pass it on to the other classes that need it.

Comment: @PalleDue "store the IErrorReport reference and pass it" that be big problem if you have many class need it and you need write it in evey single class. you will be crazy. so some times "static" class or "singleton" it's not a bad idea.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-are-drawbacks-or-disadvantages-of-singleton-pattern for a discussion of the pro's and con's of the singleton pattern. The solution I have sketched is quite simple and straightforward. If something more advanced was required, I would prefer to use IOC, rather than a singleton.